# How to extract word from string?

Tags: java, regex, string, url, extract

Suppose I have a string:
String message = "you should try http://google.com/";

Now, I want to send "http://google.com/" to a new 
String url

What I want to do is:
check if a "word" in the string begins with "http://" and extract that word, where a word is 
something that's surrounded by spaces (general english definition of word).

I have no idea how to extract the string, and the best I can do is use startsWith on the string. How to I use startsWith on a word, and extract the word?
Sorry if this is a little bit difficult to explain.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Also, what should I do to extract the word from the REGEX operation? And how should I handle it if there is more than 1 url in the string?

Comment: You should use a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). For matching URLs, [John Gruber's](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) is a good start.

Comment: I also recommend looking at the documentation for the [String class]. There's many more methods that can find stuff in a string besides `startsWith()`.

Comment: @millimoose.. My eyes pain when reading something on that link.

Comment: @RohitJain *shrug* If you mean Gruber, regardless of your opinions of that guy's opinions, the little programming-related output he's made public is very useful.

Comment: @millimoose. Yeah you're right. Efforts shown is worth appreciating. :)

Comment: Your edit is bad form on SO. Don't move the goalposts on an existing question, post new ones instead. Also, both of those are easily answered by perusing the documentation of the classes ([`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)) the answers you already got point you towards.

Comment: Honestly, ignore all the answers and use the link @millimoose included in his comment above. It may be ugly, but it's correct and will properly match all kinds of extra edge cases that we may never come up with here because it was created iteratively after trial and error that probably took days, weeks, or even months to arrive at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Pattern & Matcher classes.

```
String str = "blabla http://www.mywebsite.com blabla";
String regex = "((https?:\\/\\/)?(www.)?(([a-zA-Z0-9-]){2,}\\.){1,4}([a-zA-Z]){2,6}(\\/([a-zA-Z-_/.0-9#:+?%=&;,]*)?)?)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    String url = m.group(); //value "http://www.mywebsite.com"
}
```

This regex will work for `http://...`, `https://...` and even `www...` URLs. Others regex can be easily found on the net.

Comment: If I pass in something like `"visit http://example.com for more"` this will fail since it gives me `"http://example.com for more"`.

Comment: Correct. I want to extract only the word.

Comment: Yups forget ! It must be ok now.

Comment: I used John Gruber's REGEX instead, and used notepad to replace
'\' with '\\' and '"' with '\"' to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
String str = "blabla http://www.mywebsite.com blabla";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(http://.*)").matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    String url = (new StringTokenizer(m.group(), " ")).nextToken();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" way to perform this task is to split the String by whitespace -- String#split("\s") -- and then pipe it to the URL constructor. If the string starts with your prefix and a [MalformedURLException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/MalformedURLException.html) is thrown it is invalid. The URL class constructor is far better tested and more robust than any solution that you or I could come up with. So, use it, please and don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: So I would declare an array, do 
new URL( message );
where message is for each word in the array, and then see if there's a MalformedURLException?
Sounds complicated.

Comment: If I understand the OP right, he wants to *find* URLs in a string, not validate them. Finding what's *meant* to be a complete URL is a harder problem than just finding the longest or shortest substring starting with `http://`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Regex for this:
The following regex catches any string starting with *http://* or *https://* till the next whitespace character:

```
Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile("(http(s)?://[.^[\\S]]*)");
Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(myString);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String url = matcher.group();
}
```